# Decrypt Azure Function App Operation Secret

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I'm looking to get at an Azure function app's list of operational endpoints for each function, in particular the secret code that needs to be passed in to invoke the function.
I've tried lots of current answers in SO but all only seem to work with Function App's which use **Files** as the secret storage type.

We have a requirement to use Blob storage which is also the default in V2 function apps.

What I'm really after is the code piece that comes after the function name when it's retrieved from the Azure portal, I can manufacture all the other pieces before that myself.

For example https://mytestfunapp-onazure-apidev03.azurewebsites.net/api/AcceptQuote?code=XYZABCYkVeEj8zkabgSUTRsCm7za4jj2OLIQWnbvFRZ6ZIiiB3RNFg==

I can see where the secrets are stored in Azure Blob Storage as we need to configure that anyway when we create all the resources in our scripts.

What I'm really look for is how to decrypt the secret stored in the file. I don't care what programming language or script the solution may be written in, I'll work with it, or convert it to another language that we can use.

Here's a snippet of what the stored secret looks like in Blob storage, it's just a JSON file.

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone out there has some experience with this issue and may be able to help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now it's not supported to get the true key value programmatically. you could just view your key or create new key in the portal. You could find the description here: [Obtaining keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#obtaining-keys).

If your function is a WebHook, when using a key other than the default you must also specify the clientId as a query param (the client ID is the name of your new key):

```
https://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<funcname>?clientid=<your key name>
```

More information refer to this wiki doc: [WebHooks](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Http-Functions#webhooks).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @George Chen, I had not come across that piece of documentation before. It's unfortunate that you cannot retrieve the keys, as we're looking for an automated way to manage the whole environment and push those keys into something like a key vault so we can access them.

Comment: @Bigtoe，I checked some docs and find you could use KUDU API to get the key value. Here is the doc link.https://www.markheath.net/post/managing-azure-function-keys

Comment: Your are an absolute star, that has worked perfectly and even has examples in that Powershell.

Comment: @Bigtoe，if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: Apologies @George, I thought I had.